# How to unit test AutoMapper profile with AfterMap using IMappingAction

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, automapper

How can i unit test a profile that uses `AfterMap` with `IMappingAction` that has an injected service.

**MappingProfile.cs**

```cs
public MappingProfile()
{
    CreateMap<string, string>()
        .ConvertUsing<Core.Converter.TrimStringValueConverter>();   
    CreateMap<TestModel, TestEntity>(
        .AfterMap<AfterMapAction>();
}
```

**AfterMapAction.cs**

```cs
public class AfterMapAction: IMappingAction<TestModel, TestEntity>
{
    private readonly IAfterMapService _afterMapService ;
    public AfterMapAction(IAfterMapService aftermapService)
    {
        _afterMapService  = afterMapService  ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(afterMapService));
    }

    public void Process(TestModel, TestEntity destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var somevalue = _afterMapService.DoAction(source);
        ...
    }
}
```

**Test.cs**

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void AutoMapperTest()
{
    // Arrange
    var model = new TestModel { Id = "4711" , Name = "Test" };
    var mapper = new Mapper(new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile>();
    }));

    // Act
    var mappedObject = mapper.Map<Entity>(model);

    ...
}
```

When i run this test, i get following exception:

**System.MissingMethodException: 'No parameterless constructor defined for type 'AfterMapAction'.**

The usage of `cfg.ConstructServicesUsing` did not work. It always ends with an InvalidCastException.

How can i arrange the unit test, so *AutoMapper* can instantiate `AfterMapAction`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I could solve this by using the `IServiceCollection` within the Unit Test.

```cs
// Arrange
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddSingleton<AfterMapAction>();
services.AddSingleton<IAfterMapService, AfterMapService>();
services.AddAutoMapper(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile>());

var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var mapper = serviceProvider.GetService<IMapper>();

// Act
```

Comment: to make it work with .NET use Automapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection nuget

Answer (score 1):

Alternative variant is to use CreateMapper func to define custom IMappingAction.

```
// Arrange

var afterMapAction = new AfterMapAction(any_dependency_here);

var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
});

_mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper(x =>
{
    if (x == typeof(AfterMapAction))
    {
       return afterMapAction;
    }

    return null;
});
```